# Альтернатива imagecopyresampled  в imagemagic

Tags: gd, imagemagick, php

Друзья не подскажите какая есть альтернатива в imagemagick imagecopyresampled мне необходимо это для ресайза фоток.
сейчас у меня происходит вот так вот

```
$resizeWidth = $image->getImageWidth();
    $resizeHeight = $image->getImageHeight();
    if($resizeHeight <= $resizeWidth){
        $img_width = $_REQUEST['size'];
        $img_height = intval(($resizeHeight)/($resizeWidth/$_REQUEST['size']));
        $fill_w = 0;
        $fill_t = round(($_REQUEST['size']-$img_height)/2);
    }else{
        $img_width = intval($resizeWidth/($resizeHeight/$_REQUEST['size']));
        $img_height = $_REQUEST['size'];
        $fill_w = round(($_REQUEST['size']-$img_width)/2);
        $fill_t = 0;
    }

    $image->resizeImage($img_width, $img_height, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
```

проблема в том что мне ресайз делается на ура НО мне нужно делать так что если я допустим задаю параметр размера 75 то он производил ресайз изображения по полученной формуле а потом выравнивал его на какую нить прозрачную подложку 75 на 75 и потом выдавал в одно изображение...

Comment: А что значит "Альтернатива"? Если там нет никакой imagecopyresampled

Comment: Может Вы спрашиваете о том, как объединить два изображения (поскольку "ресайз делается на ура")? Вероятно это Imagick::compositeImage